# What is the notation for differentiating with respect to a variable "d"

Tags: calculus

This might be a trivial question, how I wasn't able to get a good answer. I have a large body of work where I use a variable with the symbol `d`. If I want to show the derivative of another quantity `Y(d)` with respect to `d`, can I still use `dY/dd` ? I have never come across `dd` like this.

Comment: True, it kind of looks funny. There are $25$ other letters in the lower-case English alphabet. Then there is upper case, Greek, and so on.  But if one insists on using $d$, and Leibniz notation, there is no real alternative to $dd$. True, you could use the fashionable straight $d$ for the first $d$. But that might be even worse.

Comment: Since $Y$ is a function of one variable, you could use the prime notation to denote the derivative, i.e. $dY/dd = Y'$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Agreed. It just that I have several figures and lots of text with this variable embedded. I didn't expect that I would encounter a situation where I would have to differentiate with respect to this variable. I might eventually have to change it, but since this came up, I thought it might be a good idea to get an answer from the experts.

Comment: @André: Perhaps that should be an answer. I'm also curious how $\mathrm dY/\mathrm dd$ could be "worse" than $dY/dd$; surely at worst it is "no better". *Edit*: Hmm, now that I look at it, it does look kind of odd.

Comment: @ℝⁿ: Yes but not odder than upright d's look with other letters, I think.

Comment: I see no problem with dropping Leibnitz notation and using prime notation, until you get into finding indefinite integrals or multivariable calculus where you have to work with differentials, surface or volume integrals, or compute line integrals.

Comment: If you are only using 1 variable, perhaps try, for a function $Y(d)$, $Y'(d)={{\partial Y}\over{\partial d}}$?  Why must $\partial$ be used only for more than one variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only using 1 variable, perhaps try, for a function $Y(d)$, $Y'(d)={{\partial Y}\over{\partial d}}$?  Why must $\partial$ be used only for more than one variable? It certainly looks better to me, and if you can live with $\partial d$ as a differential, you can even keep Leibnitz notation. $\int_C\ f(Y,d)(\partial s)=\int_C\ f(Y,d\sqrt{\partial Y^2 +\partial d^2}$ seems to me easy to read and is not likely to cause problems when you want ${{\partial f}\over {\partial Y}}$ or ${{\partial f}\over {\partial d}}$. Moreover, if you have a lot of d's, a global search and replace to change dd to $\partial d$ can let the computer do the work rather than you.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion. I think replacing the $dd$ with $\partial d$ might be the best course of action for me. Next time, I'll probably avoid using $d$ as a variable, if there is even a remote possibility of having to represent differentiation.

Answer (score 1):

True, $dd$ kind of looks funny.

There are 25 other letters available in the lower-case English alphabet. Then there is upper case, Greek, and so on.

But if one insists on using $d$ as a variable, **and** Leibniz notation, there is no useful alternative to $dd$. True, one could switch in general to the fashionable straight d for the first d. But $\textrm{d}d$ perhaps looks even worse.